# how to find key listener on any where in window

Tags: java, windows, swing, listener, adapter

i have develop one java desktop application which monitor the work of the user . now i want to count the number of key press and number of mouse click anywhere in system.

that means when ever my application is running and user typing something in browser or open any folder then mouse click and key press count is increment.

can i use below code

```
 KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher()
```

if yes then how it is possible? and if i cannot use that then please say me fast how it is possible. i am beginner in java

Comment: Not through Java, you'll need to find a JNI/JNA solution...excuse me while I write a quick `Robot` program that randomly generates keystrokes and mouse clicks....

Comment: This is not possible bye the code which you have write

Comment: what is JNI/JNA i am beginner so i don't know what is it

Comment: @user3363563 Loot at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think this example defiantly help full to you this is the example of the hooks system calls Global Keyboard Listener

```
    import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
        public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

                if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                        GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
                }
        }

        public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
        }

        public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
                }
                catch (NativeHookException ex) {
                        System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
                        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

                        System.exit(1);
                }

                //Construct the example object and initialze native hook.
                GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is possible to do it using Windows [HOOKS system calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is easily accesible from C or C++ ([Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c5699/Hooking-the-Keyboard.htm)).

For Java you will need to wrap these system calls.
There is a library which already makes this work for you but I have never tested it:

https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/